# spring ftp integration using 'local-filename-generator-expression '

Tags: spring-integration

I want to read file from ftp and store it locally as the same path as the remote file under my root directory (I need it to process the file).
The remote file path is dynamic and changes according to the filter.
(The file is processed when the `service-activator` call the method pull)

```
<int:channel id="ftpChannel">
      <int:queue/>
</int:channel>

    <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
        channel="ftpChannel" session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
        auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="true"
        remote-directory="/"
        remote-file-separator="/" temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
        local-filename-generator-expression ="/+=#this"
        local-directory="${mfg.root.dir}">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="50000" />
    </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

     <bean id= "directoryFilter" class="il.co.mit.mfg.filter.FilterClass" scope="prototype" >
        <property name="channelType" value="****"/>
        <property name="rootFolder" value="${mfg.root.dir}"/>
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="pubSubChannel">
       <int:queue/>
   </int:channel>
    <int:channel id="output">
      <int:queue/>
     </int:channel>

    <file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundfolder"
        channel="pubSubChannel"
        directory="${mfg.root.dir}"
        prevent-duplicates="false">
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="5000">
          <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager"  />
    </int:poller>

    <int:service-activator id="inputFileServiceActivator"
        input-channel="pubSubChannel" method="pull" ref="typeAdapter" output-channel="output">
</int:service-activator>

    <bean id="ftpSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="*****" />
        <property name="port" value="21" />
        <property name="username" value="******" />
        <property name="password" value="******" />
        <property name="clientMode" value="0" />
        <property name="fileType" value="2" />
        <property name="bufferSize" value="100000" />
    </bean>
```

I have been trying to use the `local-filename-generator-expression` but I am not sure how to write the SpEL expression.
I am kind of new to this please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by

> The remote file path is dynamic and changes according to the filter.

The remote path is a literal; the filter can't change it.

```
remote-directory="/"
```

If you simply mean you want to use the remote file name as the local file name - that will be the default - just omit the `local-filename-generator-expression`.

If you truly want dynamic paths rather than filenames, it would be better if you use the [ftp outbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway); there you have complete control over the remote and local paths.

Comment: it works, it creates the folder but  it doesn't put the file, I get exception

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$LsEntry cannot be cast to java.io.File

Comment: You need to show the complete stack trace, but that implies you are using a `FileListFilter` from `spring-integration-file` instead of an `Sftp...Filter` from `spring-integration-sftp`.

Comment: No for sftp it's the same filter class as in docs.spring but the generic is LsEntry class

Comment: That doesn't gel with the class cast exception; you need to show exactly what you are using and the stack trace.